# Convert 'Hel\x6co wor\x6cd!' to Hello World! in C#

Tags: c#

Consider this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18721/hello-world-without-repetition/18808#18808).

I saw the question and tried to convert JavaScript to C# code:

This is the JavaScript code:

```
alert('Hel\x6co wor\x6cd!')//alert hello world
```

What I got when I converted to C#

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello w\x6fr\x006cd!");//write hello world!
```

How does compiler know convert the code to `hello world!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you see Character, hex, octal, decimal in this URL

http://defindit.com/ascii.html

Answer (score 2):

In Java the characters are represented by bytes (two hex digits). In C# characters are represented by two bytes (four hex digits).

This is the reason why the second \x should start by two zeros : else the d letter at the end of the world word would be taken as the hexadecimal third digit and 0x6cd (1741) is the arabic letter "Ya queue" (ۍ) in Unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII](http://defindit.com/ascii.html)

`\x6c` is `hexadecimal numbers` = `l`

Therefore When compiler compile the code it converts into `Hello world.`